# css flex shrink container width to fit its items

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying a list of same sized items in a flex div. I've aligned them to the left. However I'd like the list to be centred as a whole. Any suggestions about how to do this?

Please try to snipped below.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.list').toggleClass('hack')
});
```

```css
.item {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: skyblue;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .list-container {
      width: 100px;
      background-color: grey;
      flex-direction: row;
      display: flex;
    }
    .spacer {
      flex: 1;
    }
    .list.hack {
      width: 84px;
    }
    .list {
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='list-container'>
  <div class='spacer'></div>
  <div class='list'>
    <div class='item'></div><div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div><div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='spacer'></div>
</div>

<button>Toggle fixed list width (hack)</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way is to insert the "item" elements to a new div, setting:

```
  <div style="margin:0 auto;width: 85px;">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
```

and also applying `.item{float:left;}`

Comment: based on your solution, I've created the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fxz6o726/4/

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough when you set *justify-content: center;* to *.list*?

Then if you need to make the standalone item to be aligned to left, you can set its *margin-right: 42px;* (to compensate the space next to it)

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same without using flex

**HTML**

```
  <div class='list'>
    <div class='item'>item 1</div><div class='item'>item 2</div>
    <div class='item'>item 3</div><div class='item'>item 4</div>
    <div class='item'>item 5</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list{
     display:inline-block;
     background-color: grey;
     width:100px;
     clear:both;
     justify-content: center;
}

.list .item{
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    background-color: skyblue;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
.list .item:last-child{
    margin-left:25%;
}
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Umamaheswaran/avfc3838/) for JSFiddle sample

Comment: I was looking to have the list as a whole centred and the items aligned to the left. Please check the fiddle to the solution below.